# Create Qt UI forms as a shared library in Qt Creator and using them in Eclipse C++ project

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I am developing an application and the main IDE is Eclipse Juno(CDT) on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.

I have the following constraints:

1. Application must be developed on Eclipse (Non-GUI part)
2. Must Use Qt4 for GUI
3. Application target platform is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server version 6.3
4. I am new to Linux Development Environment, Eclipse and Qt.

What I have done:

I have developed the main application on Eclipse.
I have created modules like interacting with hardware as shared libraries.

What I want to do (if possible, and practical):

I want to create the GUI module of the application using Qt Creator, as a library and use it in the main application on Eclipse.

What I am trying:

1. Created the GUI in eclipse without using any .pro files or Qt Creator. But since I am new to Qt and Eclipse and Linux, and time constraints, I want to make it quicker, easier and well planned approach to complete the tasks. This looks very tedious (obviously) as I am better off using an IDE and visual tools to create GUI.

Can someone help me with the following:

1. Am I doing the things right, is my approach of creating GUI module as a shared library and using it in another application a naive approach?

If I missed out detailing anything or if you need more info please let me know.

Thanks.